# Bigquery Stack Overflow tags. How do I find strongly related tags?

Tags: tags, google-bigquery, implementation

Suppose I were to ask show me all the tags and questions related to 'data-structures' I would like to see related tags like '2-3-4 trees', 'binary-search-trees', 'dfs' etc. and not see many questions filtered on the language criteria. If I tried finding out the most commonly occurring bigrams with data structures then even C++ and Python would come but I would rather try to see core data structure tags come up.

How do I go about implementing this?

What if have tried is to get tags that occur the most with data structures by querying on data structures first. And then also went and looked at all the tags and fetched their common partners to see if data structures occur. If they occur pairwise then I assuming they are strongly associated. But how can I take this logic one more step ahead to fetch more related tags?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood - you already got code that gives you "related" tags for given tag!

If so - to get rid of languages and leave only "strongly" related tags you need to find (using the same exact code/query you already have) tags related to "programming-languages" tag and exclude them from your result!

Bingo! (hopefully)

P.S.

When I did this:

below initial list

```
algorithm       java            c++                 c 
python          linked-list     tree                arrays 
c#              binary-tree     binary-search-tree  dictionary 
database        graph           sorting             javascript 
performance     list            recursion           stack 
hash            hashtable       time-complexity     queue 
hashmap
```

got "trimmed" to

```
linked-list         tree        arrays              binary-tree 
binary-search-tree  dictionary  database            graph 
sorting             list        recursion           stack 
hash                hashtable   time-complexity     queue 
hashmap
```

so, entries as below got removed

```
algorithm   java    c++         c 
python      c#      javascript  performance
```

Comment: where did the reference code and answers come from? can't find them in the question :)

Comment: from how I understood the question - PO can identify related tags just by "finding out the most commonly occurring bigrams with data structures" - so I assumed he actually did this :o) - the rest in my answer is just an example

Comment: I tried bigrams, trigrams as well quadgrams to gather the hierarchy. Even though this served well, I could not come up with a definite hierarchy.

Comment: For finding similar tags I applied skipgrams from gensim. Words similar to data-structures game me Binary-Tree, Binary-Search-Tree, Big-O and so on in this order.

Comment: Whatever way you use/used to find related tags - just apply my suggestion to improve result. My answer does not propose any new algorithm here - just small trick :o) that is possible because you know what exactly kind of noise (languages) you want to remove.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to accomplish it that if a user enters that he wants to focus on data-structures and binary-search-tree then I display him all the questions focusing on those tags only and not getting very specific to questions like binary-tree and errors that are rare. For example, someone might put up a question on binary tree and c# but the question might be focusing more on error related to c# and not binary tree in general, and this question might have been tagged either with data-structures-binary-tree->c#->binary-tree

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to communicate! StackOverflow is not a forum for discussions - but rather Question / Answer site to help programmers with `specific` questions. After answers provided those which were helpful expected to be voted up and one of questions (if any qualified) to be accepted. If you have follow up questions  - just post new question and someone here will answer it. That is how it works here at SO. Hope this makes sense to you and you will comply :o)

Answer (score 0):

I'm defining a ratio:

`(how many times a_tag has shown up with b_tag)` /
`(how many times b_tag has shown up without a_tag)`

Results for 'data-structures' look like the results you are looking for:

[image]

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION targetTag() AS ("data-structures");

WITH split_tags AS (
  SELECT SPLIT(tags, '|') tags
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions`
  WHERE tags LIKE '%|%'
)

SELECT *, ROUND(c/notc,4) ratio_related
FROM (
  SELECT tag, COUNT(*) c, (
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM split_tags b, UNNEST(tags) btag
      WHERE targetTag() NOT IN UNNEST(b.tags) AND btag=tag
    ) notc
  FROM split_tags, UNNEST(tags) tag
  WHERE targetTag() IN UNNEST(tags)
  GROUP BY 1
)
WHERE notc>0
AND c+notc>20
ORDER BY 4 DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Isn't this similar to fp-growth or apriori algorithm? I acheived the same using fp-growth but there were cases for example when binary-search-tree came up with data-structures->tree->BST fewer times than tree->BST. I also applied gensim word2vec to get better representations of words and then applied kmeans clustering putting k=100. The tags were very well clustered but I could not gather a proper hierarachy.

Comment: there's no perfect way.. just replying to the question with one way to get results similar to what you were asking for